# concatenate strings and coalesce

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation, concatenation

I have a query that selects rows from three different tables:
`TableA`, `TableB` and `TableC`.

One field of my query has to be the concatenation of the field `Name` in each table like the following alias:

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    B.Name,
    C.Name,
    CONCAT(A.Name, ' / ', B.Name, ' / ', C.Name) AS Full_name
FROM ...
```

The query joins the three tables using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. In some cases I get odd results if one of the table does not have entries as the following table:

```
--------------------------
|Table A |Table B|Table C|
--------------------------
|My      |Name   |       |
--------------------------
|My      |       |Is     |
--------------------------
|My      |Name   |Is     |
--------------------------
```

And the trailing / are visible like this one:

```
1) My / Name /
2) My / / Is
3) My / Name / Is
```

I should generate the following results but I do not want to use CASE so I was wondering if I can play with COALESCE, ISNULL and CONCAT all together

**Expected Result**

```
1) My / Name
2) My / Is
3) My / Name / Is
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When adding ' / ' and Name, you get null if name is null. Therefore you can remove them simply by adding.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    A.Name,
    B.Name,
    C.Name,
    CONCAT(A.Name, ' / '+ B.Name, ' / '+ C.Name) AS Full_name
FROM 
...
```

Sample in [**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0036af/4).

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would go for is:

```
STUFF(CONCAT(' / ' + A.Name, ' / ' + B.Name, ' / ' + C.Name), 1, 3, '')
```

The premise being if any of your values are `NULL` then `' / ' + NULL` will also be null, but by appending `' / '` to the start of everything, then you know you will always end up with `/` at the start, so you can safely remove the first 3 characters with the STUFF function.

A slightly extended example would be

```
SELECT  *,
        [Concat] = STUFF(CONCAT(' / ' + A, ' / ' + B, ' / ' + C, ' / ' + D), 1, 3, '')
FROM    (VALUES
            ('A', 'B', NULL, 'D'),
            ('A', NULL, 'C', NULL),
            ('A', 'B', 'C', NULL),
            ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
            ('A', NULL, NULL, 'D'),
            (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
            (NULL, 'B', 'C', NULL)
        ) T (A, B, C, D);
```

Comment: this is a better solution than mine in situations where first value can be null

Answer (score 0):

Just another method:

```
SELECT
    A.Name as AName,
    B.Name as BName,
    C.Name as CName,
    CONCAT(A.Name, 
           CASE WHEN B.Name IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' END, 
           B.Name, CASE WHEN C.Name IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' END,  
           C.Name) AS Full_name
FROM 
......
```

Result:

```
ANAME   BNAME   CNAME   FULL_NAME
My      Name    (null)  My / Name
My      (null)  Is      My / Is
My      Name    Is      My / Name / Is
```

Sample output in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0036af/2).